# Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'TYPE_TEXT' error after upgrading - magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, magento-1.6

i am stuck with an issue. After upgrading my site from 1.5 to 1.6 i am getting this error

"Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'TYPE_TEXT' in /var..../app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/sql/xmlconnect_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.13-1.4.0.14.php on line 49"

Please help me..

Answer (score 2):

The line in question is this:

```
->addColumn('category', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 60, array(
```

But if you upgraded the code correctly this error should not appear.
As you can [see here](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.6/lib/Varien/Db/Ddl/Table.php#L50) the constant `TYPE_TEXT` is defined.
The constant was added in 1.6 and did not exist in [1.5](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.5/lib/Varien/Db/Ddl/Table.php).
My hunch is that you did not upgrade the `lib/Varien` folder, or you have a copy of the old class `Varien_Db_Ddl_Table` in your `local` code pool folder.

Comment: Thanks Marius.. i have upgraded via magento connect by changing mage - latest to 1.7. Could you advise, is it good to copy all lib/varien from 1.7 to my magento? Could you advise me what should i really do now? Thnks in advnce.

Comment: Get a clean copy of the version you want to use and copy it over your magento instance. Override all the files if needed. Just don't do this on a live env. Backup first.

Comment: Thanks Marius.. so copying lib/varien folder along needed or copying all files from lib? Please advise.

Comment: Copy ALL files from lib. There might be other changes that you need for the new version.

Comment: Yes..i did what you told.. but i now get with this eror: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_XmlConnect_Model_Resource_Setup::getIdxName() in /var/../app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/sql/xmlconnect_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.13-1.4.0.14.php on line 60. I have replaced all lib folders.

Comment: Replace all the app/code/core files also

Comment: i think its all gone wrong.. a:5:{i:0;s:188:"Error in file: "/var../app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.5.9.9-1.6.0.0.php" - Can't retrieve entity config: core/file_storage";i:1;s:1152:"#0 /var/../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...') I have replaced core files. but now i get this error.